# Concate string with Max Value for auto ID in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracleforms

I want to Generate Auto ID concat String in Oracle Form 6i without using Sequence:

```
EXAMPLE
EMP1
EMP2
EMP3
EMP4
```

Whats error in this Trigger:

```
SELECT concat('EMP',TO_CHAR(NVL(MAX(EMP_ID),0) + 1))
INTO :EMP_Block.EMP_ID FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMP_ID LIKE 'EMP%';
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you not want to use a sequence?  You need to think how your approach will deal with uncommited data from another session.  Suppose you select a "max" value of "5", but before you commit, some other session also selects the max value -- they also will get "5" and try to use that.  Now you've got two separate sessions working with a max value of 5 and no knowledge of the other.  And if you try to do some sort of enquing (like SELECT FOR UPDATE or placing an explicit lock) you kill performance because all sessions needing this will have to line up behind each other.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `EMP_ID` is `varchar`. Without filtering `EMP` from `EMP4`, you cannot add a number to it. You need to use something like below in `concat`. I am not able to test it but let me know if you still see any problem.

```
concat('EMP',to_char(replace(max(emp_id),'EMP','')+1))
```